# How can I determine the Vo?

Tags: circuit-analysis, zener, homework

[image: schematic]

I think both of the Zener diodes in reverse bias and I think the output will be  4 V. Am I right? If I am wrong please explain the answer.

Comment: 4V would mean there is 16V across the lower diode

Comment: Two x 8V zeners in series will have around 16V across them - with V increasing rapidly as I increases. In this case with ideal supplies an immense current will flow and any real world zeners will die.

Comment: We don't hand out homework solutions here, so you need to explain your attempts at solving this yourself. Show us **all** of your work. Then ask a **specific** question.

Answer (score 1):

If that's a homework problem, you copied it wrong. It doesn't make sense. You're connecting  24 volts across 16 volts worth of zeners. If the zener diodes had higher zener voltages - greater than 12 volts - your answer could be correct, but I doubt that was the assignment.